# Write each of the following arguments in argument form. Then, use the rules of inference to show that each argument is valid.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

Let () be “ has taken Calculus I,” () be “ has taken Program Design I,” and () be “ has
permission from the instructor to enroll in this class,” where the domain consists of all students in
this class.

Every student in this class has taken Calculus I or Program Design I. Every
student who has not taken Calculus I but has taken Program Design I, has permission
from the instructor to enroll in this class. Therefore, every student who does not have
permission from the instructor to enroll in this class has taken Calculus I.

Comment: What have you tried on this problem? People are more prone to answer your question if you show your work and results so far.

Comment: Which rules of inference are you allowed to use?

Comment: I understand how to use the rules of inference but I cannot come up with what I seem the correct way to quantify these.

Comment: @JohnLarkos - It seems unusual that you understand the inference rules for quantifiers but you don't understand the meaning of quantifiers. Anyway, if you change your mind and tell me which inference rules you are allowed to use (or at list which kind of deductive system: sequent calculus, natural deduction, Hilbert system, etc.) I can show you how to prove that the argument is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that an expression of the form "Every student in this class..." refers to whatsoever element of the domain, thus they should be translated by a universal quantifier, i.e. $\forall x \dots$

Concretely,

1. "Every student in this class has taken Calculus I or Program Design I" can be translated by
   $$ \forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x))$$
2. "Every student who has not taken Calculus I but has taken Program Design I, has permission from the instructor to enroll in this class" can be translated by
   $$\forall x \, ((\lnot P(x) \land Q(x)) \to R(x))$$
3. "Every student who does not have permission from the instructor to enroll in this class has taken Calculus I" can be translated by 
   $$\forall x \, (\lnot R(x) \to P(x))$$

Let us prove that the argument is valid.

First, let us fix an *arbitrary* $c$ in the domain. We prove that under the hypotheses $ \forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ and $\forall x \, ((\lnot P(x) \land Q(x)) \to R(x))$ and the *further* hypothesis $\lnot R(c)$, then $P(c)$ holds.

1. $ \forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x))$  -- hypothesis
2. $\forall x \, ((\lnot P(x) \land Q(x)) \to R(x))$ -- hypothesis
3. $\lnot R(c)$ -- hypothesis
4. $(\lnot P(c) \land Q(c)) \to R(c)$ -- universal instantiation of 2. by $[c/x]$
5. $\lnot(\lnot P(x) \land Q(x))$ -- modus tollens
6. $P(c) \lor \lnot Q(c)$ -- De Morgan
7. $P(c) \lor Q(c)$ -- universal instantiation of 1. by $[c/x]$
8. $P(c)$ -- resolution

A well-known low of logic called Deduction Theorem says that if you can derive $B$ from the hypotheses $A, A_1, \dots, A_n$, then you can derive $A \to B$ from the hypotheses $A_1, \dots, A_n$.

Therefore, from the derivation above we conclude that there is a derivation of $\lnot R(c) \to P(c)$ from the hypotheses $ \forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ and $\forall x \, ((\lnot P(x) \land Q(x)) \to R(x))$. 
But such a derivation is valid for an *arbitrary* $c$ (there is no hypothesis concerning $c$). Hence, by applying the rule of universal generalization, we conclude that $\forall x \, (\lnot R(x) \to P(x))$ holds under the hypotheses $ \forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ and $\forall x \, ((\lnot P(x) \land Q(x)) \to R(x))$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. We are allowed to use Modus ponens, Modus tollens, Hypothetical Syllogism, Disjunctive syllogism, addition, simplification, conjunction, resolution. The rules of propositional logic as well as the Rules of Inference for Quantified Statements. I.e. Universal and General Instantiation/Generalization.

Comment: @JohnLarkos - I added a proof that that the argument is valid using your inference rules.